# Is the same port acting as both client and server?

Tags: networking, port, tcp, netstat

i find something strange in this netstat output. the output is taken using `netstat -a -n -o -p TCP` command on win 7.

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
 TCP    127.0.0.1:55486        127.0.0.1:55487        ESTABLISHED     5808
 TCP    127.0.0.1:55487        127.0.0.1:55486        ESTABLISHED     5808
```

Please note these two lines. both local and foreign address is localhost. but how come the ports are paired? out of two ports `55486` and `55487` which one is the server port and which one is the client port?

from what i understand, the `local-address` column denotes the client side of a TCP connection and the `foreign-adress` column denotes the server side. From this output it seems that the same port is behaving as both client **and** server.

I dont understand how is this possible with TCP?

[image: netstat with paired ports]

Comment: What is process 5808?

Comment: @Scott, 5808 is javaw.exe, it it hosting a jetty server. listening on `127.29.232.39:55484`. plz see the second last line in screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line: `TCP    127.0.0.1:55486        127.0.0.1:55487        ESTABLISHED     5808`

Is stating the client is connecting to the port on 55487 for the server while the client uses port 55486.

Line:  `TCP    127.0.0.1:55487        127.0.0.1:55486        ESTABLISHED     5808`

is stating the server is connecting back to the client on port 55486 from 55487.

TCP requires the "3-way handshake" to set up the connection between a client and server.

The client connects to the a server (part 1 of the 3 way handshake). The server responds acknowledging the connection (part 2). The client responds to the acknowledgement with its own acknowledgement (part 3).

TL;DR - Client generally uses random port to connect to a server with a specific port. The server responds back to that machine using the random port. The client and server are *NOT* on the same port.

Comment: ... *is stating the server is connecting back to the client on port 55486 from 55487* ... somehow i missed this. thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad I was able to help you understand :)

Answer (score 3):

I can’t quite tell how much of this you understand now,
so allow me to be a little bit pedantic.

Clearly you understand the concept of client and server, so it surprises me
that you write, “the `Local Address` column denotes the client side of a TCP connection
and the `Foreign Address` column denotes the server side.” 
That’s wrong; the `Local Address` column denotes the ***local*** side of a TCP connection
and the `Foreign Address` column denotes the ***foreign*** (or **remote**) side. 
In other words, the `Local Address` column denotes the (TCP) socket
that a process *on your computer* is using (i.e., a socket that your computer *owns*),
and the `Foreign Address` column denotes the socket that the local socket is connected to. 
As you seem to understand, processes on your computer can function as servers,
so local sockets can be server sockets --
and then the corresponding client socket would be listed as “foreign”.

Things start to get confusing when a client process on your computer
connects to a server process on your computer. 
Now, this one connection represents two local sockets --
and `netstat` reports one line for each; one showing the client as local
and the server as foreign (even though it really is a local socket),
and one the other way around.

Your situation is just a little bit more confusing. 
Your jetty server (process 5808) is, of course,
creating sockets and accepting connections on them -- that’s what servers do. 
But it is creating many sockets at once. 
(By necessity, they are on different port numbers;
the OS won’t allow multiple sockets with the same protocol and port number to co-exist.) 
And it seems to be using random (OS-assigned) port numbers. 
For example, as you pointed out, it is listening on port 55484. 
I’m not familiar with jetty, so I don’t know whether that is normal.

If you examine your `netstat` output closely, you’ll see that local process 184,
using a socket on port 8081, has a connection to process 5808 / port 55482.

The part that I find really weird is that process 5808
has connected *to itself* on several of these sockets. 
So you have several TCP connections where both sockets are held,
not just on the same host, but *in the same process*. 
I don’t think we can tell for sure which end is the client and which is the server. 
I would actually guess that the lower port number is more likely to be the server,
but that is just a guess.

Comment: i really appreciate your being *pedantic*, i believe now i have a much clear picture. the part where process 5808 connects to itself, the process hosts a server **and** a client i should have made two JARs, but packaging required one, so i packed both of them in one JAR. This is not normal for jetty, but for my application. i expected to see one line for each of the connections, but got confused when saw two. it is unfortunate that we can mark only one as answer and upvote only once, but i'll do what i can.

Answer (score 0):

It is not unusual situation. `127.0.0.1` is valid IP address which your program listens to. Program can listen on this address. Program can connect to this address as well. This complies to Client-server architecture. You have client and you have server. They can be on different computers but in same time they both can be on one computer.

For example, when you use Google web site your computer is client and Google's web server is server. There is connection between your computer and Google's server.

You can have your own Web server running on your computer and listening on interface `127.0.0.1`. Open your browser and type `127.0.0.1` - as result you will see web page from your Web server. In this situation `netstat` will show same thing.

To answer your question:

> From this output it seems that the same port is behaving as both client and server.

No. One port is client, another is server. Notice - it **does not** say

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:55486        127.0.0.1:55486        ESTABLISHED     5808
```

It says:

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:55486        127.0.0.1:55487        ESTABLISHED     5808
 TCP    127.0.0.1:55487        127.0.0.1:55486        ESTABLISHED     5808
```

Which does make sense.

Comment: well it didnt make sense then. but guess it does now. thanks.

Comment: Once the connection is made, is it correct to say that the concept of client/server fades away? I mean, since both processes are now established then both processes are now client and server at the same time. I also want to mean, that the client / server concept is only up to at the beginning when the client is connecting to the server.

Comment: @daixtr, It does not fade away. Client/server model is applicable regardless of state of connection. As long as server is running and ready to accept new connections from clients, it is providing service to them. This is why it's called server. For example, a client could connect to a database server, send it queries and receive results. They both are sending and receiving data, but the server continues to be the server, and the client continues to be the client.